# Send Multiple Text Fields in Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, input

I have the following code in my file:

```
<table width="100%" class="friends">
<tr>
    <th width="50%">Friends Name</th>
    <th>Friends Email</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendname[]" id="friendname[]" class="validate[minSize[4]]" min="4" placeholder="John &amp; Jane Doe" style="width:80%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendemail[]" id="friendemail[]" class="validate[custom[email]]" min="4" placeholder="jandjdoe@example.com" style="width:80%;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendname[]" id="friendname[]" class="validate[minSize[4]]" min="4" placeholder="John &amp; Jane Doe" style="width:80%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendemail[]" id="friendemail[]" class="validate[custom[email]]" min="4" placeholder="jandjdoe@example.com" style="width:80%;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendname[]" id="friendname[]" class="validate[minSize[4]]" min="4" placeholder="John &amp; Jane Doe" style="width:80%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendemail[]" id="friendemail[]" class="validate[custom[email]]" min="4" placeholder="jandjdoe@example.com" style="width:80%;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendname[]" id="friendname[]" class="validate[minSize[4]]" min="4" placeholder="John &amp; Jane Doe" style="width:80%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendemail[]" id="friendemail[]" class="validate[custom[email]]" min="4" placeholder="jandjdoe@example.com" style="width:80%;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendname[]" id="friendname[]" class="validate[minSize[4]]" min="4" placeholder="John &amp; Jane Doe" style="width:80%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendemail[]" id="friendemail[]" class="validate[custom[email]]" min="4" placeholder="jandjdoe@example.com" style="width:80%;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendname[]" id="friendname[]" class="validate[minSize[4]]" min="4" placeholder="John &amp; Jane Doe" style="width:80%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendemail[]" id="friendemail[]" class="validate[custom[email]]" min="4" placeholder="jandjdoe@example.com" style="width:80%;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendname[]" id="friendname[]" class="validate[minSize[4]]" min="4" placeholder="John &amp; Jane Doe" style="width:80%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendemail[]" id="friendemail[]" class="validate[custom[email]]" min="4" placeholder="jandjdoe@example.com" style="width:80%;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendname[]" id="friendname[]" class="validate[minSize[4]]" min="4" placeholder="John &amp; Jane Doe" style="width:80%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendemail[]" id="friendemail[]" class="validate[custom[email]]" min="4" placeholder="jandjdoe@example.com" style="width:80%;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendname[]" id="friendname[]" class="validate[minSize[4]]" min="4" placeholder="John &amp; Jane Doe" style="width:80%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendemail[]" id="friendemail[]" class="validate[custom[email]]" min="4" placeholder="jandjdoe@example.com" style="width:80%;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendname[]" id="friendname[]" class="validate[minSize[4]]" min="4" placeholder="John &amp; Jane Doe" style="width:80%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="friendemail[]" id="friendemail[]" class="validate[custom[email]]" min="4" placeholder="jandjdoe@example.com" style="width:80%;" /></td>
</tr>
```

And the following as my PHP Code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['friendname']) && !empty($_POST['friendemail']) && is_array($_POST['friendname']) && is_array($_POST['friendemail']) && count($_POST['friendname']) === count($_POST['friendemail'])) {
    $err[] = "Please enter in your friend's details.";
}

$name_array = $_POST['friendname'];
$email_array = $_POST['friendemail'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++) {
    $name = $name_array[$i];
    $email = $name_array[$i];
}
```

However my code isn't echoing anything.

I got the code for the above from [insert multiple fields using foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156505/insert-multiple-fields-using-foreach-loop)

I have other fields inside my form and they work fine, but for some reason these don't. Does anyone know of a way to do what I'm looking for based on the code above? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (array_combine($_POST['friendname'], $_POST['friendemail']) as $name => $email) {
 echo $name . " - " . $email . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: thanks @BeatAlex that's really helpful! But unfortunately my code shows the arrays as being empty. I put `echo $_POST['friendname'];echo $_POST['friendemail'];exit();` at the top of my submit code and it just came back `ArrayArray`

Comment: You can't "echo" an array in PHP. Put var_dump($_POST['friendname']);var_dump($_POST['friendemail']);exit(); on top of your page

Comment: @nahime sorry you are correct. I changed it to `echo '<pre>';var_dump($_POST['friendname']);echo '</pre>';echo '<pre>';var_dump($_POST['friendemail']);echo '</pre>';exit();` and that gave me results, but I use `if(!empty($_POST['friendname']) && !empty($_POST['friendemail']) && is_array($_POST['friendname']) && is_array($_POST['friendemail']) && count($_POST['friendname']) === count($_POST['friendemail'])) {` for validation and that isn't giving me anything. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your `var_dump` return?

Comment: You're checking that both have same length. Look at the var_dump to see if that's true. BTW, have you tried @BeatAlex solution without validating before?

Comment: @BeatAlex It returns 2 arrays with the details I've entered `array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Name 1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Name 2"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
  [7]=>
  string(0) ""
  [8]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "john@example.com"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "joe@example.com"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
  [7]=>
  string(0) ""
  [8]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

Comment: OK, so now use the code that I submitted as an answer WITHOUT any of the code that you have tried. (Just comment yours out).

Comment: @BeatAlex that returned my results fine. Thanks. :). Any idea on a way I can validate it now?