# Reading multiple textfield values using array in php

Tags: php, html, forms

Can you please help me in this context.

```
<form action="sample.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first[]" />
<input type="text" name="second[]" />
</form>
```

I am using this code in a loop and I need to get all the values in another page.
How can I get these value as array in another page.

Comment: So you also loop the `form`? Just create one form and put all generated `input` inside it.

Comment: "Another page?" Is this `sample.php` or a completely different page? What's the point of `first[]` and `second[]` in this example?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022933/send-multiple-text-fields-in-array-in-php

Comment: I've edit my answer below, please accept if it helped you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```
 $first=$_POST['first'];
  $second=$_POST['second'];
  foreach($first as $key=>$first){

   echo 'Your first value'.$first.'Your second value'.$second[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use $_POST array in the ***sample.php*** page

PHP's $_POST Array, taken from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php):

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

first, add s submit button to your form, it should look like this:

```
<form action="sample.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="first[]" />
  <input type="text" name="second[]" />
  <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

and in ***sample.php***:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This is the most simple example,

once you get the hang of it, I recommend you read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/) on topics such as:

[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

> htmlspecialchars — Convert special characters to HTML entities

Comment: can you give an example

Answer (score 0):

You can access it as array

```
$_POST['first'][0] // 0 will be index for single
```

to list all just loop

```
foreach($_POST['first'] as $first) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values will end up in `$_POST`, and because you're using the [] syntax, you'll get an array. So, to get your first array, do:

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
```

You could then iterate over it like so:

```
foreach ($first as $item) {
    ...
}
```