# Laravel forms - array of same field

Tags: php, arrays, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

**I'm trying to replicate this logic:**

[insert multiple fields using foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156505/insert-multiple-fields-using-foreach-loop)
- using laravel 4 and blade.

**I tried this:**

```
<div>
    {{ Form::select('linkType[]', array('Facebook', 'Twitter','Other')) }}
    {{ Form::text('linkUrl[]') }}<br>
    {{ Form::select('linkType[]', array('Facebook', 'Twitter','Other')) }}
    {{ Form::text('linkUrl[]') }}
    ...
</div>
```

**But that gives me this laravel error:**

ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (view:...)

Any idea how to fix that?
Thanks

---

**Update**

A few of these works: `{{ Form::text('linkurl[]') }}` So that is written as it should.

A few of this also works:

```
<select name="linktype[]"/>
    <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
    <option value="twitter">Twitter</option>
</select>
```

So the problem is 99% sure in the:

```
{{ Form::select('linkType[]', array('Facebook', 'Twitter','Other')) }}
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Which exact Laravel version are you using? Can you post the full stack trace and preferable your entire view where you're creating the form?

Comment: Laravel 4 homestead -
I have no idea how, but after a few hours of testing and commenting lines away while testing it suddenly started worked with the code from the opening post. The only thing that changed was a lable that I removed... I will answer my question and post my full code as edu material.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div>
        {{ Form::select('linkType[]', ['Facebook', 'Twitter','Other']) }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

generates:

[image]

Comment: As commented under the opening post. After hours of trying to debug the original code started working. (I did remove the label for the select.) But I just found out ->withInput() was killing it, it cannot give back an input[] array. And as I think I had set my label for "linkType[]" that might have been the problem. Solution was to set withInput(Input::except('linkUrl','linkType')) so it does not give back the links the user submitted. Will answer fully and type out findings later this week.