# Saving multiple form data to mysql using php

Tags: php, html

I have a table form which has a add new row button which upon clicked adds a new row to the table. I am trying to save all the rows in MySQL on clicking save button.

The code I wrote saves only one row no matter how many row I add. Could someone please tell my what am I doing wrong.

I searched Google but couldn't get anywhere.

Here are my codes:

save.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $row_data = array();
    foreach($_POST['category'] as $row=>$category){
        $category = mysql_real_escape_string($category);
        $itemName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemName'][$row]);
        $brand = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['brand'][$row]);
        $model = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['model'][$row]);
        $sellingPrice = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sellingPrice'][$row]);

        $row_data[] = "('$category','$itemName','$brand','$model','$sellingPrice')";
    }
}
if(!empty($row_data)){
    $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sale(Category,ItemName,Brand,Model,SellingPrice) VALUES".implode(',', $row_data));

    if(!$insert_query){
        echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
    }else{
        echo "Data Saved Successfully";
    }
}
?>
```

and this is my html form

```
<form name="form1" id="myForm" action="saveSale.php" method="post">
                    <tr class="cloneme">
                        <td><input type="text" name="category[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="itemName[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="brand[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="model[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sellingPrice[]"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="eventButtons">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save">
            <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Clear"  class="btn">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: @candle I generate them dynamically using jquery on button click

Comment: please go through : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156505/insert-multiple-fields-using-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I dont have enough reputation I am adding my comment as answer.

Your code is fine. It should work. There might be problem while you are cloning the row, may be it is not getting added under the `form` tag. You can verify it by dumping the `$row_data` variable.

Please share your javascript code which makes clone of the row, it will help us to solve your problem.

Comment: here are my javascript which makes thhe clone of the row: `$('#addNew').on('click',function(){
  var clone = $('table.itemTable tr.cloneme:first').clone();
  console.log(clone);
  clone.append("<td><div class='deleteAdded'>Remove</div></td>")
  $('table.itemTable').append(clone);
 });`

Comment: Can you try adding `<table class="itemTable"> ` line under the `form` tag. As your code is not showing opening  `table` tag. This is the issue. Use developer tool and check where your new cloned row get added.

Comment: thank you.... this was the problem. I put the form  tag in the wrong place in the wrong place. Now I did exactly like you said and it is working. Tank you

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting data outside the for loop so it inserts only the last row or data.. What you have to do is to place insert query within `foreach or for loop`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $row_data = array();
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($_POST['category']);$i++){
        $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]['category']);
        $itemName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]['itemName']);
        $brand = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]['brand']);
        $model = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]['model']);
        $sellingPrice = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]['sellingPrice']);
        $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sale(Category,ItemName,Brand,Model,SellingPrice) VALUES ('$category','$itemName','$brand','$model','$sellingPrice')"); 
        if(!$insert_query){
            echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
        }else{
           echo "Data Saved Successfully";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Narendra Sisodia is right. INSERT statement should be in the loop.

Comment: @Narendra Sisodia I tried your codes but it is givinh me this error: Undefined Offset 0 in all the lines

Comment: @IndraGotamey can you please show us the array structure that you are receiving within $_POST so can make `for` loop for that particular

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your query in for loop by counting the `array` value using `count($_POST['category'])`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $row_data = array();
    for($i= 0; $i <count($_POST['category']);$i++){
        $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]['category']);
        $itemName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]['itemName']);
        $brand = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]['brand']);
        $model = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]['model']);
        $sellingPrice = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$i]['sellingPrice']);
        $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sale(Category,ItemName,Brand,Model,SellingPrice) VALUES ('$category','$itemName','$brand','$model','$sellingPrice')"); 
        if(!$insert_query){
            echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
        }else{
           echo "Data Saved Successfully";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your codes but it is givinh me this error: Undefined Offset 0 in all the lines