# Dynamic PHP / MySQL Upload Form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a dynamic PHP / MySQL upload form wherein data fields can be dynamically added or removed, and all of this data can be uploaded to a database from one button.

Here's what this looks like with dynamic `<textarea>` elements that can be added and removed:

```
    <form method="post" action="dynamicForm.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <!--Dynamically Added Paragraphs Go Here-->

        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" id="upload">

    </form>

    <button onclick="addParagraph()">Add Paragraph</button>

<script>

    //add textarea div and associate "Remove" button
    function addParagraph(){
        $("form").append('<div><textarea name="paragraph"></textarea><button class="remove">Remove</button></div>');

   //remove added paragraph
   $(document).on('click', ".remove", function(e) {
   $(this).parent().remove();
   });

</script>
```

Here's some example PHP that I could use for this:

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

    $db = mysqli_connect('','','','');

    $paragraph = $_POST['paragraph'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (paragraph) VALUES ('$paragraph')";

    mysqli_query($db, $sql);

}
```

Each of the added paragraphs have the name `paragraph`. If there are 5 elements with the name `paragraph`, and the PHP code is looking for an element with name `paragraph`, what happens in this situation? Does all the data get uploaded, or just the first element with name `paragraph`? Will an error be thrown? If this won't upload all the added paragraphs, how can I get the PHP to upload all of them?

**EDIT: Possible Solution**

```
<script>

//changed name value to array "paragraph[]"
function addParagraph(){
    $("form").append('<div><textarea name="paragraph[]"></textarea><button class="remove">Remove</button></div>');


</script>



if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

    $db = mysqli_connect('','','','');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (paragraph) VALUES ('$paragraph')";

    $paragraph_array = $_POST['paragraph'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($paragraph_array); $i++){

        $paragraph = mysqli_real_escape_string($paragraph_array[$i]);

        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    }

}
```

Comment: It'd overwrite. Use the name `paragraph[]` then iterate over that in the PHP. You also are open to SQL injections, parameterize the query.

Comment: well for one thing `<form method="post"> action="dynamicForm.php">` you need to remove the `>` after "post".

Comment: Oops, accidentally threw that in when typing the question. Thanks

Comment: you'll also need to use a `foreach` or `count` against the multi-array. Your edit won't work. The `[]` belongs in `<textarea name="paragraph[]">` only. Edit: this comment as per https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44752505/2

Comment: @chris85 I've added an edit to the question at the end with what you're talking about. Is that the right direction?

Comment: No, you need that client side, e.g. `$("form").append('<div><textarea name="paragraph[]"></textarea><button class="remove">Remove</button></div>');`. Then iterate over `$_POST['paragraph']` because it then is an array.

Comment: And you cant upload anything without declaring  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I've updated the possible answer. I honestly am not sure how to do this foreach looping through an array. I'm assuming the `mysqli_connect` will come before it, and then inside the loop will be the SQL statement and the myslqi_query. Is that right?

Comment: @nodws, thanks I've updated.

Comment: In any case, thanks for all the help - I'm reading up on how exactly to implement the foreach loop.

Comment: I actually am submitting files but took out all that stuff for simplicity. Added it back so that others would focus on the problem posted rather than extraneous errors

Comment: Oh, okay, in that case it is needed (with provided code though it wouldnt have been).

Comment: Are there any good resources I can look into on how to write the foreach loop?

Comment: I've updated the possible answer, and have taken some help from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156505/insert-multiple-fields-using-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0):

Once user click upload button, all entered data will be uploaded even though there are multi input elements with the same name.

In the other hand in server side you can only access to the last entered valued in the input element that has the repeated name.

If you want to access to all values you should give input elements different names or just add "[]" at the end of repeated name and in the server side you will get all entered values encapsulated in array.

```
<?php var_dump($_POST);?>
```

array(2) { ["paragraph"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "t1" [1]=> string(2) "t2" [2]=> string(2) "t3" [3]=> string(2) "t4" } ["upload"]=> string(6) "Upload" }